# Closest thing to XCode, Objective-C on Windows (Not Hackintosh), perhaps interface-builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have to do some XCode/iPhone SDK work tomorrow, and i would like to know how I can prepare on Windows.  What is the closest I can get to XCode and/or Objective-C developer experience, ideally IOS or similar Objective-C GUI.

Can also be say an interface-builder that works in a similar way.

I know Hackintosh/Vmware solutions, I think it would take a bit to long, especially since i have an AMD laptop with not to much RAM (i do have an Intel netbook)

*Remark 1*
I might actually have access to an old  Power-PC Mac (i saw in some other threads that this might be possible).  Though the question still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get is [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/) and its associated tools. It's emphatically not the same as Apple's environment, but it's derived from the same lineage. Cocoa was derived from the OpenStep frameworks, as is GNUstep (and GNUstep tries to track Apple's additions, though they lag a lot). Xcode and Interface Builder evolved from the OpenStep Project Builder and Interface Builder, which were also the basis for GNUstep's ProjectCenter and Gorm. Gorm can even open Interface Builder's nibs.

Comment: The last time I used GNUstep it was difficult to get it set up properly, both running apps and building apps, and *waaaaay* behind Apple's implementation. Looking at the source for GNUstep, it was riddled with comments like "this is a hack" etc.

Comment: Yep. I would not generally recommend GNUstep, but it is the only real answer to what Olav asked for.

Answer (score 11):

Xcode, iPhone and IB are substantially different development platforms to anything I have seen on Windows, in both large and small ways. You have practically zero chance of gaining any insight into Xcode/iPhone programming by tomorrow without using the real thing.

The little time you have would be best spent reading up as much as you can online.

Comment: Actually, even with a real Macintosh you have zero chance of gaining an insight into using Xcode and Cocoa in one day, if you are starting from zero.

Comment: @Olav, If you have access to GCC then perhaps write a hello world program in objective c. It can be compiled without a Mac. It will give you an idea what objective C is about. Getting more insight beyond this, before tomorrow, is unlikely.

Comment: Watch even part of the Stanford iPhone Application Development course (CS193P) available on iTunes U.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Marcelo, your time would be best spent reading. The [iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action) is a good place to start. I suggest starting with the [Objective-C primer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/) and moving on to the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

For an introduction to the tools (Xcode, simulator, etc) the [iOS Development Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/000-Introduction/introduction.html) is a pretty good overview.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with Marcelo without a Mac OS running somewhere your chances will be very limited. 
You can probably start trying out some ObjC with GNUStep for Windows. But i actually did not try it.

http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html

Comment: also http://www.cocotron.org/ is a cocoa implementation for windows, but without the GPL license.