# How to run xcode or playground on Windows?

Tags: xcode, windows, swift-playground

I have a windows laptop . 
I want to run xcode or its playground to practice on the Swift? Is there any software or solution for that?

please answer with the possible links to have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
1.  [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

2.  [Closest thing to XCode, Objective-C on Windows (Not Hackintosh), perhaps interface-builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407534/closest-thing-to-xcode-objective-c-on-windows-not-hackintosh-perhaps-interfa)

Comment: I'll suggest to use [Swiftstubs](http://swiftstub.com/) online compiler for Playground stuff.